# create a set of continuous variables from a factor variable and a continuous variable

Tags: stata

In Stata, I have a factor variable with 50 levels (`state`) and an integer-valued variable (`year`).  I want to create 50 new variables: 50 interactions of `state` indicators with the `year` variable.  Is there a way to do this without writing 50 lines of code?

I can produce the 50 state dummies with `tabulate state, generate (state)`, but I don't know how to get further than that without writing a line to create each individual state-year variable.

I want to use the new state-year variables in a regression.  Stata's factor notation makes it easy to include the state-year variables as regressors without creating them beforehand (e.g., with a command like `regress y i.state#c.year`), but some add-on functions don't support factor notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `xi`, both as a stand-alone command to create indicator and interaction terms, and as a command prefix. A nonsensical example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

* stand-alone
xi i.rep78*mpg

* as prefix
xi: regress price i.rep78*mpg
```

Run `help xi` for all the details.

### Edit

To make this a bit clearer, suppose the `regress` command did not admit the use of either *factor variable notation* or the `xi:` prefix. Then using the `xi` stand-alone syntax you could create the indicator and interaction terms (which answers your original question) and then use those terms with the `regress` command:

```
sysuse auto, clear

xi i.rep78*mpg
regress price mpg _Irep78* _IrepXmpg*
```

(Remember to use Stata's help capabilities. Running `search interactions`, for example, leads you to **xi......Interaction expansion**.)

Comment: Thank you -- I have used `xi` with success in some cases.  But it doesn't help with the particular add–on function that I am using (`ivreg2`), it doesn't help.  I still get an error message of type r(101): "factor variables and time-series operators not allowed."

Comment: That's right. Not all commands work with the `xi:` prefix, but you can use the stand-alone syntax to create the interactions and then feed them in to the relevant command.